# Confusion Concerning Int Data Type in C++

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I know that int is a 4-byte datatype. Since it only takes up 4 bytes in memory, why does the compiler pre-allocate or initialize 8 bytes worth of memory?

[image: enter image here]

Comment: What does `sizeof(a)` say? My guess, not 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I know it's 4-bytes. It's an Int. My question is, why does the compiler fill in 8 bytes of data with CC before I step into the code (F10)?

Comment: Why not? It's just marking the stack with `CC` presumably to detect uninitialized values, so provided it does at *least* `sizeof(a)` it's fine. Try with `int x[32]` and see how many you get.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I should make my question a little clearer. Why does the compiler fill in 8 bytes of data when it knows that Int will only ever be 4 bytes and nothing more?

Comment: Why does it matter so long as it's masking out any *potential* values? Do you have anything else in that code? If there's another variable later on it'll be masked out in advance.

Comment: It might not matter but I am asking a very compiler-specific question. I simply just want to know why the compiler is filling in 8 bytes of data when initializing an Int (4-byte) datatype. If you don't know the specific answer to that question, not a problem; saying why does it matter doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: A) Show us the rest of the code that generated this, I have a feeling there's another stack variable there you aren't showing. B) This isn't defined behaviour so there doesn't have to be an explanation. It's a convenience for debugging. Nowhere in any spec does it say it has to be precisely X bytes, just that it would make sense it's at *least* X bytes.